# Speech recognition question

Tags: speech-recognition

I am searching for a software that will translate speech to text but if it does not recognise a word, it will simply write a close resemblance to a word only misspelled, for example, if I say the word house, but it does not recognise house, it will write something like hause but not a different word all together. I considered perhaps trying to match spoken words to a dictionary of a different language (i.e, using a French dictionary when saying words in English) however, it will only write the closest words it finds in French which does not benefit me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that normal human speech does not exactly resemble words, so speech-to-text software has to guess at something reasonable.  So, to avoid guesses, you may not want speech-to-text software, but something more like a speech-phoneme estimator.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I am searching for. The idea is that I need to translate words that are out of grammar (in essence, translate gibberish) but at the moment, I can't find a reliable source for it.

Comment: If you find any of the answers to your questions useful, please mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't hear about free software that could transcribe audio to text but there are some free online solutions. For example [Speechnotes](https://speechnotes.co/)  will translate speech recorded over a microphone to text. The [IBM Watson](https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/) Speech to Text service will do the same but will also let you upload your pre recorded audio file. There is also Adobe Premiere Pro which can transcribe audio to text. Premiere Pro is more for video production and it's not a free software but you can download a fully functional trial. Here is a tutorial how to transcribe in Premiere: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4P50OL2_I0